Functional completeness over a structure
The set of propositional connectives $\{\wedge,\vee\}$ is of course not functionally complete; correspondingly, the logical vocabulary $\{\forall,\exists,=,\wedge,\vee\}$ is not sufficient for developing all of first-order logic. However, the situation is different over the natural numbers in the following sense:

Every first-order formula $\varphi(\overline{x})$ in the language of arithmetic is equivalent, in terms of the relation it defines in the structure $(\mathbb{N};+,\times,0,1)$, to one in which the only logical symbols occurring are $\forall,\exists,\wedge,\vee$, and $=$.

Proof: By "pushing negations inside" and replacing $\neg s=t$ with $\exists x(x+1+s=t \vee x+1+t=s)$. Note that even though we only need $\vee$ for handling inequalities, the process of pushing negations inside will introduce $\wedge$s even if the original formula only contained $\vee$s (and will similarly flip quantifiers), so we can't do better than the set $\{\forall,\exists,=,\wedge,\vee\}$ via this argument - and indeed it's not hard (if rather tedious) to show that this is optimal.
In general, I'm not very familiar with results focusing on the Boolean aspects of first-order formulas. The following seems like a fun test question:

Question: Is there a first-order structure $\mathfrak{A}$ in a finite language $\Sigma$ over which $\{\wedge,\vee,\leftrightarrow\}$ is functionally complete but $\{\wedge,\vee\}$ isn't?

Precisely: it should be the case that

every formula $\varphi(\overline{x})$ is equivalent over $\mathfrak{A}$ (= defines the same relation on $\mathfrak{A}$ as) some formula $\psi(\overline{x})$ using only the logical symbols $\{\forall,\exists,=,\wedge,\vee,\leftrightarrow\}$, but

the previous bulletpoint fails if we don't include $\leftrightarrow$.



Here is a very ad hoc idea that might be an example (I couldn’t actually figure out how to prove $\leftrightarrow$ is necessary, but it does seem like it should be): let $\Sigma$ consists of a constant symbol $0$ and two binary function symbols $f, g$. Let $\mathfrak{A}$ have infinite domain and $f, g$ be so chosen s.t.: 1. For each $x$, there are infinitely many $y \neq x$ s.t. $f(x, y) = 0$ and also infinitely many $y \neq x$ s.t. $f(x, y) \neq 0$; 2. For each $y$, there are infinitely many $x \neq y$ s.t. $f(x, y) = 0$ and also infinitely many $x \neq y$ s.t. $f(x, y) \neq 0$; …


Whenever $x, y$ is s.t. $x \neq y$, $f(x, y) = 0$, we have $g(x, y) = 0$; 4. Whenever $x, y$ is s.t. $x \neq y$, $f(x, y) \neq 0$, we have $g(x, y) \notin {0, f(x, y)}$; 5. There are infinitely many $x$ s.t. $f(x, x) = 0$ and also infinitely many $x$ s.t. $f(x, x) \neq 0$; 6. Whenever $x$ is s.t. $f(x, x) = 0$, we have $g(x, x) \neq 0$, and ${g(x, x): f(x, x) = 0}$ is infinite; 7. Whenever $x$ is s.t. $f(x, x) \neq 0$, we have $g(x, x) = 0$…


Then $x \neq y$ is equivalent to $f(x, y) = 0 \leftrightarrow g(x, y) = 0$, so bullet point 1 is fine. I would suspect that $x \neq y$ is in particular not equivalent to a formula using only ${\forall, \exists, =, \wedge, \vee}$ for logical symbols. At least it seems that way to me intuitively, but admittedly I don’t have any idea how to prove that.

@DavidGao I think that works! And here's the remaining piece: any ${\forall,\exists,=,\wedge,\vee}$-formula is preserved by taking quotients, and we can whip up a structure with the properties you give which has lots of nontrivial congruences (unless I'm having a silly moment). If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Another good example of this concept is any field $F$ whose theory is model-complete in the language of rings (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). By model-completeness, any formula is equivalent over $F$ to an existential formula. Now inside the quantifier-free part, we can push the negations inside to the atomic formulas, and then replace $\lnot (p(x)=q(x))$ by $\exists y,(y(p(x)-q(x))=1)$. So ${\exists,\land,\lor,=}$ is sufficient for first-order definability.

@NoahSchweber I’m not sure I understand the argument you’re suggesting. After all, even if $\mathfrak{A}$ admits a nontrivial congruence $\sim$ and $x \neq y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x, y)$ for some ${\forall, \exists, =, \wedge, \vee}$-formula $\varphi$ in $\mathfrak{A}$, it does not mean this equivalence still holds in $\mathfrak{A}/\sim$, so I’m not sure what you had in mind for the next step of the argument. (After all, $(\mathbb{N}; +, \times, 0, 1)$ has a nontrivial congruence, namely everything is equivalent to each other, no?)

@DavidGao Sorry, I also should have said that after quotienting by the congruence the resulting algebra should be isomorphic to the starting one. (In the light of morning I'm no longer convinced that we can in fact ensure that this exists, but this is what I had in mind last night.)

@AlexKruckman You can do better: in any field, every existential formula is equivalent to a pp formula (i.e. ${\exists,\land,=}$), and if the field does not include the algebraic closure of the prime field (or of a larger field from which you are allowed to take parameters), to an existentially quantified identity (${\exists,=}$). Thus, ${\exists,\land,=}$ and ${\exists,=}$ are sufficient for FO definability in algebraically closed and real-closed fields, respectively.

You use $f=0\lor g=0\equiv fg=0$, and $f=0\land g=0\equiv h(f,g)=0$, where $h(x,y)$ is the homogeneous polynomial $y^dh_0(x/y)$ for $h_0(x)$ a polynomial without a root of degree $d\ge1$.

This is basically the idea I proposed in comments, coupled with the OP's own suggestion to consider quotient structures:
Let $\Sigma = \{0, f, g\}$ where $0$ is a constant symbol and $f, g$ are binary function symbols. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the structure with underlying set $\mathbb{N}$. Let $0^\mathcal{A} = 0$ and $f^\mathcal{A}$ be defined by,
$$f^\mathcal{A}(x, y) = \begin{cases}
0 &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is even}\\
x &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is odd}\\
\max\{x, y\} &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are even}\\
x &, \text{ if }x\text{ is odd and }y\text{ is even}\\
y &, \text{ if }x\text{ is even and }y\text{ is odd}\\
\min\{x, y\} &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are odd}
\end{cases}$$
Let $g^\mathcal{A}$ be defined by,
$$g^\mathcal{A}(x, y) = \begin{cases}
1 &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is even}\\
0 &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is odd}\\
1 &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are even}\\
x &, \text{ if }x\text{ is odd and }y\text{ is even}\\
y &, \text{ if }x\text{ is even and }y\text{ is odd}\\
\max\{x, y\} &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are odd}
\end{cases}$$
Then the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by $[0]_\sim = [2]_\sim =\{0, 2\}$ and $[n]_\sim = \{n\}$ for $n \neq 0, 2$ is a congruence relation. Indeed,
$$\begin{split}
f^\mathcal{A}(0, 0) = 0 &\sim 2 = f^\mathcal{A}(2, 0)\\
f^\mathcal{A}(0, 2) = 2 &\sim 0 = f^\mathcal{A}(2, 2)\\
f^\mathcal{A}(0, x) = x &\sim x = f^\mathcal{A}(2, x) \; \text{if }x \neq 0, 2\\
f^\mathcal{A}(0, 0) = 0 &\sim 2 = f^\mathcal{A}(0, 2)\\
f^\mathcal{A}(2, 0) = 2 &\sim 0 = f^\mathcal{A}(2, 2)\\
f^\mathcal{A}(x, 0) = x &\sim x = f^\mathcal{A}(x, 2) \; \text{if }x \neq 0, 2\\
g^\mathcal{A}(0, x) = 1 &\sim 1 = g^\mathcal{A}(2, x) \; \text{if }x\text{ is even}\\
g^\mathcal{A}(0, x) = x &\sim x = g^\mathcal{A}(2, x) \; \text{if }x\text{ is odd}\\
g^\mathcal{A}(x, 0) = 1 &\sim 1 = g^\mathcal{A}(x, 2) \; \text{if }x\text{ is even}\\
g^\mathcal{A}(x, 0) = x &\sim x = g^\mathcal{A}(x, 2) \; \text{if }x\text{ is odd}
\end{split}$$
Thus, $\mathcal{A}/\sim$ is a well-defined $\Sigma$-structure. I claim that $\mathcal{A} \simeq \mathcal{A}/\sim$. Indeed, let $\pi: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}/\sim$ be defined by,
$$\pi(x) = \begin{cases}
[0]_\sim &, \text{ if }x = 0\\
[x + 2]_\sim &, \text{ if }x \geq 2\text{ and }x\text{ is even}\\
[x]_\sim &, \text{ if }x\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
One easily verify that $\pi$ is a bijection. $\pi(0^\mathcal{A}) = [0]_\sim = 0^{\mathcal{A}/\sim}$. Moreover,
$$f^{\mathcal{A}/\sim}(\pi(x), \pi(y)) = \begin{cases}
[0]_\sim &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is even}\\
[x]_\sim &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is odd}\\
[y + 2]_\sim = \pi(\max\{x, y\}) &, \text{ if }x = 0\text{ and }y \geq 2\text{ is even}\\
[x + 2]_\sim = \pi(\max\{x, y\}) &, \text{ if }y = 0\text{ and }x \geq 2\text{ is even}\\
[\max\{x + 2, y + 2\}]_\sim = \pi(\max\{x, y\}) &, \text{ if }x \neq y; \, x, y \geq 2; \text{ and both }x, y\text{ are even}\\
[x]_\sim &, \text{ if }x\text{ is odd and }y\text{ is even}\\
[y]_\sim &, \text{ if }x\text{ is even and }y\text{ is odd}\\
[\min\{x, y\}]_\sim &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are odd}
\end{cases}$$
Matching the definition case-by-case, we see that $f^{\mathcal{A}/\sim}(\pi(x), \pi(y)) = \pi(f^\mathcal{A}(x, y))$. For $g$,
$$g^{\mathcal{A}/\sim}(\pi(x), \pi(y)) = \begin{cases}
[1]_\sim &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is even}\\
[0]_\sim &, \text{ if }x = y\text{ is odd}\\
[1]_\sim &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are even}\\
[x]_\sim &, \text{ if }x\text{ is odd and }y\text{ is even}\\
[y]_\sim &, \text{ if }x\text{ is even and }y\text{ is odd}\\
[\max\{x, y\}]_\sim &, \text{ if }x \neq y\text{ and both }x, y\text{ are odd}
\end{cases}$$
Matching the definition case-by-case, we see also that $g^{\mathcal{A}/\sim}(\pi(x), \pi(y)) = \pi(g^\mathcal{A}(x, y))$. Hence, $\pi$ is an isomorphism.
Finally, in $\mathcal{A}$, we observe that, $x \neq y$ is equivalent to,
$$f(x, y) = 0 \leftrightarrow g(x, y) = 0$$
Because there are no relation symbols in $\Sigma$, the same argument showing every formula is equivalent to one using only $\{\forall, \exists, =, \wedge, \vee\}$ over $(\mathbb{N}; +, \times, 0, 1)$ shows every formula is equivalent to one using only $\{\forall, \exists, =, \wedge, \vee, \leftrightarrow\}$ over $\mathcal{A}$. However, $\leftrightarrow$ is necessary. Indeed, assume to the contrary that $x \neq y$ is equivalent to some $\varphi(x, y)$ over $\mathcal{A}$, where $\varphi$ uses only $\{\forall, \exists, =, \wedge, \vee\}$. As $0 \neq 2$, we have $\varphi^\mathcal{A}(0, 2)$. Any formula using only $\{\forall, \exists, =, \wedge, \vee\}$ is preserved after taking quotients, which can be easily verified by an induction. Thus, $\varphi^{\mathcal{A}/\sim}([0]_\sim, [2]_\sim)$. But $\mathcal{A} \simeq \mathcal{A}/\sim$, so over $\mathcal{A}/\sim$, $x \neq y$ is also equivalent to $\varphi(x, y)$. Thus, $[0]_\sim \neq [2]_\sim = [0]_\sim$, which is a contradiction.

Great, thanks! (I can't award the bounty yet, some time limit - I think 24 hours? - has to pass first.)
